# Actionscript 3.0 Error 1120: Access of undefined property even on instanced objects

Tags: actionscript-3

I've been getting error 1120: Access of undefined property on two different symbols for a simple radial gravity simulator in Flash. So far the following fixes have not worked:

1. Giving the instance a name. The most common advice for this problem is to name an instance for the object. In the properties panel for one of my symbols it says that it's a Graphic and "Instance of: Earth" (sorry, I can't post images until I have 10 rep)
2. Putting it into a package. This doesn't make any difference for me.

Here's the code:

```
var yVelocity:Number = 0;
var xVelocity:Number = 0;
var gravityConstant:Number = 1;
var earthMass:Number = 5000;
var canPlay:Boolean = true;

function findAcceleration():Number {
    var distance:Number = Point.distance(Ship, Earth);
    return gravityConstant * earthMass / Math.pow(distance, 2); 
}

function findAngle():Number {
    var angle:Number = Math.atan((Ship._y - Earth._y) / (Ship._x - Earth._x));
    return (180 / Math.PI) * angle; //converts from radians to degrees
}

function findXAcceleration():Number {
    return findAcceleration() * Math.cos(findAngle());
}

function findYAcceleration():Number {
    return findAcceleration() * Math.sin(findAngle());
}

function gravity():void {
    yVelocity += findYAcceleration();
    xVelocity += findXAcceleration();
    Ship._x += xVelocity;
    Ship._y += yVelocity;
}

do
{
    gravity();
} while (canPlay == true);
```

The canPlay boolean is going to be implemented later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you export your movieclips to actionscript?

Library: Right click the movie-clip > properties > advanced > check the box "export to actionscript" write the name you wish to access the movieclip by in "class".